# asp.net mvc C# displaying \

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i display \ by using c# in a textbox .

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Can you set up the scenario, perhaps post some code of what you have tried?

Comment: i want to hardcode \ in a domain using c# . i can only write it as "\\" which is not what i need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myTextBox.Text = "\\";
```

'\' is, as you probably know, an escape character (so "\n" is new line, "\t" is tab, etc). To display a literal "\" you need to double it up.

Comment: Alternatively the @"" syntax: `myTextBox.Text = @"\";`

Comment: @Rup: that's another option, though you have to be aware that with the `@""` syntax, you need to escape " if you want a literal '"' in your string...